# Flutter: control the Blue Light Filter of the Screen

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to control the Blue Light Filter setting of the phone from your Flutter App?

*(The Blue Light Filter automatically reduces the blue color of the screen, usually according to the time of the day.)*

Comment: I think you can do so with **flutter platform specific code** take a look at the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). And if you choose to use *platform specific code* take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/webianks/Crimson).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it exactly fits what you want, but you could put the entire widget tree in a stack, and put a colorFilter or a boxDecoration with a tinted color in an ignorePointer above the widget tree.

```
-MaterialApp
 - Stack
    - Your widget tree
    - IgnorePointer
      - colorFilter
```

Comment: I am looking to change the main setting. Anyway according to [BlendMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html) `BlendMode.darken` should take the lowest value for each channel, so if combined with `Colors.red` should blue (and green) be set to zero!?
So using `ColorFiltered (colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red,BlendMode.darken),..)` on the main MaterialApp widget seems to do the job, what is the purpose to add IgnorePointer?
But I am not sure that this is all the effect of the official filter and how this one would add up to it since I can't disable the main one.